# Issue passing JSON object to HttpServlet

Tags: java, jquery, json, servlets

I have an html form that I want to pass to a servlet when the form is submitted. The form info is:

```
<form method="post" action = "/directory" name="dirinit" id="srchform">
```

and the jQuery code I'm trying to use to post is:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form").on("submit", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            var formData = JSON.stringify(jQuery("form").serializeArray());
            $.post("/directory", formData)
            });
        });
```

The servlet is set up as:

```
public class NewDirectory extends HttpServlet{


  public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException 
    {
        super.init(config);
    }

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException 
  {

    doPost(request, response);
  }


  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
          throws ServletException, IOException 
{
      response.setContentType("text/json");
      String form = request.getParameter("formData");
      System.out.println(form);
}
}
```

My web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>NewDirectory</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>newdirectory</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>edu.msu.is.directory.newdirectory</servlet-class>

 </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>newdirectory</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/directory</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

When I try to post the form data, I get a 404 error saying that the url was not found. I'm pretty new to servlets, so I'm not even sure I'm setting the the servlet up correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be something like this :

**Servlet :**

```
package edu.msu.is.directory;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class NewDirectory extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public NewDirectory()
    {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/json");
        String form = request.getParameter("formData");
        System.out.println(form);
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
...
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>NewDirectory</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>edu.msu.is.directory.NewDirectory</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NewDirectory</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/directory</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
...
```

**Html Form :**

```
<form method="post" action="directory" name="dirinit" id="srchform">
```

**Javascript :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on("submit", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var formData = JSON.stringify(jQuery("form").serializeArray());
        $.post("directory", formData)
        });
    });
```

**Note :** If you are getting 404 error that means either you are accessing different url or your servlet/jsp is not mapped properly.

Here you set your action url as `/directory` which should be either only `directory` or `/YourProjectContextRootPath/directory`.

Answer (score 0):

`<servlet-class>edu.msu.is.directory.newdirectory</servlet-class>`

is case sensitive, should be

`<servlet-class>edu.msu.is.directory.NewDirectory</servlet-class>`